# Error while installing SSSD

Tags: command-line, compiling, gcc, make, sssd

I have the following error when running `make install` on sssd-2.1.0. I have tried all the options which says recompile using `-fPIC` to no avail. Please help. I have also used `--enable-shared` in my config.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.a(ceval.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_PyRuntime' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
libtool:   error: error: relink '_py3sss.la' with the above command before installing it
Makefile:10957: recipe for target 'install-py3execLTLIBRARIES' failed
make[3]: *** [install-py3execLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/anirudh/Anirudh/sssd-2.1.0'
Makefile:34607: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anirudh/Anirudh/sssd-2.1.0'
Makefile:33513: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anirudh/Anirudh/sssd-2.1.0'
Makefile:34601: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

[image: Image shows error]

Comment: Perhaps try using the `-no-pie` compiler/linker option, instead of `--enable-shared`?

Comment: That did not work :(